# jvm classloading issue (defineClass1)

Tags: jvm, classloader

App starts but on some stage many threads stops on `ClassLoader.defineClass1` (see sample brace below), other bunch of threads waits for them to free classloading locks. What can be the issue? Environment: linux, jdk 21.0.1.

```
"l-offsite-9" #137 [189] prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=3462.59ms elapsed=318.76s tid=0x00007fcb70217c00 nid=189 runnable  [0x00007fcb2bbfd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(java.base@21.0.1/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@21.0.1/ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@21.0.1/ClassLoader.java:1105)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@21.0.1/SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@21.0.1/BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(java.base@21.0.1/BuiltinClassLoader.java:741)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@21.0.1/BuiltinClassLoader.java:665)
    - locked <0x0000000353da2bd8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@21.0.1/BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@21.0.1/ClassLoaders.java:188)
```